# I am getting "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: vba

I am getting

> No value given for one or more required parameters

I am new in Excel VBA. What is wrong with the query? Below is the code I am using to get the value from a access data based and I want to search database using Name ID.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of your code.  Include the actual code.

Comment: You are missing a space between select and *

Comment: putting image of code is unreachable. put the exact code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If nameID is a string then you should use the line below:

```
MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM ContDb WHERE NameID = '" & Val(Me.TxtBox1.Value) & "'"
```

But since you're using the Val-function, NameID might be an integer and then you should use:

```
MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM ContDb WHERE NameID =" Val(Me.TxtBox1.Value)
```